# Read 2d array and list result in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have following 2D array

```
name_list = [['Orange', '5'],['Mango','6'],['Banana','3']]
```

I want to get each fruit name alone with its count and print it using a python code. So how do I read above array to extract the data (inside for loop)

I need print out as

```
Name:Orange<br/>
Count:5<br/>
Name:Mango<br/>
Count:6<br/>
Name:Banana<br/>
Count:3<br/>
```

Comment: Please include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
name_list = [['Orange', '5'],['Mango','6'],['Banana','3']]

for item in name_list:
    print("Name: {}".format(item[0]))
    print("Count: {}".format(item[1]))
```

Comment: this is a bad way to loop though a Python `list`. A better one would be `for item_pair in name_list:` that let's you forget about the indexes.

Answer (score 2):

You can unpack your list like this:

```
for name, amount in name_list:
    print("Name:{}".format(name))
    print("Count:{}".format(amount))
```

Comment: Instead of formatting the string, you could just do `print("Name:", x, sep="")` iff using python 3.x. Furthermore `x` and `y` are bad names. You should name them after what they are: `name` and `amount`.

Comment: @RichardNeumann Thanks for tip, naming is very important, just wanted to give answer in the first place :)